# Is $\partial (A\times B)$ jordan measurable when both of $A$ and $B$ are jordan measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} $  is *Jordan measurable*, $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m} $ is *Jordan measurable*, then $A \times B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ is  *Jordan measurable*?

We have $$\partial (A\times B)=\left( \partial A \times  \overline{B}\right)\cup\left( \partial B \times  \overline{A}\right)$$

If  $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}, B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}  $  are  *Jordan measurable*, hence the *Lebesgue measure* of $\partial A  $ and $\partial B $ is zero .(i.e. $m(\partial A )=0，m(\partial B )=0$.)

For every $\epsilon >0$, there is a finite mumber of rectangels $ R_{1},\cdots,R_{K} $ such that $\partial A\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{K}R_{i}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{K}\mathcal{v}(R_{i})<\epsilon .$ $\mathcal{v}(R_{i})$ is the volume of $R_{i}$. But we can not say $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathcal{v}(R_{i}\times \overline{B})<\epsilon.$

Similarly,

For every $\epsilon >0$, there is a finite mumber of rectangles $ S_{1},\cdots,S_{N} $ such that $\partial B\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{N}S_{i}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{v}(S_{i})<\epsilon .$$\mathcal{v}(S_{i})$ is the volume of $S_{i}$. But we can not say $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{v}(S_{i}\times \overline{A})<\epsilon.$

So we must find other ways to clarify this question.
I need some hints. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\partial (A\times B)=\left( \partial A \times  
\overline{B}\right)\cup\left( \partial B \times  \overline{A}\right),
$$
then
$$
\mu(\partial (A\times B))\le\mu\left( \partial A \times  
\overline{B}\right)+\mu\left( \partial B \times  \overline{A}\right)=\mu(A)\cdot\mu(\partial B)+\mu(B)\cdot\mu(\partial A)=0.
$$